# Streaming through Excel data with Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

We have an Excel workbook that is fairly large. Around 3,300 columns and several thousand rows.

We've found that attempting to do anything with the data results in high memory usage, around 3 GB.

It appears that the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` package, when iterated, keeps a full object structure of the worksheet in memory. Generally, we are doing this:

```
var workbookPart = _document.WorkbookPart;
var worksheets = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>();

foreach(var worksheet in worksheets)
{
    var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart) workbookPart.GetPartById(worksheet.Id);
    foreach(var row in worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>())
    {
        foreach(var cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
        {
            var (_, value) = ParseCell(cell);
        }
    }
}
```

`ParseCell` simply gets the contents of the `Cell` by looking up the string value from the `SharedStringTable` on the workbook, or if it is a number, parsing the number.

Simply running this code that does nothing with the result of `ParseCell` still uses considerable memory.

When we profiled this code, we noticed that there is a `Cell` on the heap for every cell in the sheet despite our best attempts at using `IEnumerable<T>` APIs to void having large collections in memory.

This is fairly close to the recommended usage of this Nuget package.

From profiling, it *appears* the issue is that each `Cell` has a strong reference to the next `Cell`, and likewise for `Row`.

Each `Cell` has a field called and `_next` which is what is keeping each Cell with a strong root. Cell A has a strong reference to Cell B, B to C, C to D.

`Row` has a similar structure, where Row 0 has a `_next` field to Row 1, so on and so forth, so for each `Row` that we go through, it keeps a strong reference to the next `Row`.

So everything is tied together. When I looked at this with WinDbg after it processed that last `Row`, there were exactly the number of `Cell`s on the heap from `!dumpheap -stat` as the workbook contained.

The way that we are using this SDK won't scale to more rows. Is there a way to use this package more efficiently and process an Worksheet on a row-by-row basis without it keeping an object graph of the whole worksheet in memory?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm aware that very large workbooks will still use considerable memory due to the nature of how Excel files work - they are zipped XML files. However, this package is not only keeping a 30 MB XML file in memory, but several instances of related objects per-cell.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I hope someone can offer a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable solution here is to use the `OpenXmlReader` XML reader. The other key thing is to use `Elements` instead of `Decendents` to avoid looking too deep in the XML structure.

```
using (var reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (typeof(Row).IsAssignableFrom(reader.ElementType))
        {
            var row = (Row)reader.LoadCurrentElement();
            foreach (var cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                var (_, value) = ParseCell(cell);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does indeed "stream" the elements and memory usage is minimal.

Comment: Bah, I came up with [almost the exact same solution](https://gist.github.com/leftler/de248859a5be4e6aaa8b366db6ec8d0d) with just a slightly more complex `if` clause (which may be redundant), If I did not have to go to a 45 min meeting I would have gotten it first.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain sorry! Darn meetings. Hopefully it was productive and fun at least.